# Blazor - Access RenderFragment underlying type properties

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor app where there is a simple auth wrapper (wrapping the `<Router>` in `App.razor`) that looks like this:

```
@if(authService.LoggedIn)
{
    @ChildContent
}
else
{
    // Display login page
}

@code {
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Each page that might be the value of `@ChildContent` has a property `PageType` (an enum). Ex:

```
@page "/"

<div>Hello World</div>

@code {
    PageType PageType = PageType.HelloWorld
}
```

What I would like to do is use that to more granularly control auth. So, what I would like to accomplish (but can't) is this:

```
@if(authService.LoggedIn)
{
    if(authService.AuthorizedPageTypes.Contains(ChildContent.PageType))
    //----------------------------------Problem ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        @ChildContent
    }
    else
    {
        // Display "Not authorized" message
    }
}
else
{
    // Display login page
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to access the PageType of the ChildContent though. Is there some way to access the underlying type? (I tried casting to `dynamic`, but that didn't work)

I could always let each page control this, by adding a check in each page. i.e.

```
@if(authService.AuthorizedPageTypes.Contains(PageType)) {...}
else { /* Display unauthorized message */ }
```

but it shouldn't be the page's concern to validate auth. That's the point of the wrapper.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ComponentBase` was not designed with `Wrapper` functionality.  You need to build a new `ComponentBase`.  In this case you don't need it, just do as @HH suggests and use the built in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to figure out how to access the PageType of the ChildContent though. Is there some way to access the underlying type?

No.  `ChildContent` is not an object that holds a Page, it is a delegate that will create your Page component when run. That is of no use to you here.

> Is there any way to accomplish this?

In (or before) the Router you have access to the routedata only. Maybe you can authorize on the URL.

But why are you doing this DIY ?   The built-in [Authorize] lets you specify Roles or Claims.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

Make the field a static so you don't need to create an instance of the component page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    public static readonly PageType PageType = PageType.Authorized;
}
```

You can then do the following in `App`.

`GetPageType` gets the type from `RouteData` and attempts to find the field.  It calls `GetValue` on the FieldInfo object: you provide a `null` for the instance as it's a static field.  It finally checks if it's a `PageType` and casts and returns it.

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        @if (this.GetPageType(routeData) == PageType.Authorized)
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        }
        else
        {
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">Not Authorized</div>
            </LayoutView>
        }
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there is nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    private PageType GetPageType(RouteData routeData)
    {
        var propInfo = routeData.PageType.GetField("PageType");

        var pageTypeObject = propInfo?.GetValue(null);

        if (pageTypeObject is PageType)
            return (PageType)pageTypeObject;

        return PageType.None;
    }
}
```